# In LINQ expression how to get FirstOrDefault with better performance?

Tags: performance, linq, xamarin, linq-to-sql, xamarin.forms

In our Xamarin Forms app this code:

```
return database.GetAllWithChildren<Review>(x => x.ProductId == prodId, true).OrderByDescending(x => x.ReviewId).FirstOrDefault();
```

is having performance issues and it takes more time the more reviews exist for that product.

With a product with 7 reviews it took about 17 seconds which is unacceptable.

How could I optimize the performance?

After all I don't need all the reviews info, just the latest one.

It seems that this retrieves all 7 reviews and then sorts them descending and then gets the first in the list.

Is there a way to get only that one with the max ID?

Comment: Seventeen seconds sounds excessive, even if you load all seven reviews. You may need to add some missing indexes to your RDBMS.

Comment: I had I lot of performance issues using LINQ and the SQLiteNetExtensions. It seems like it always loads all data on memory before executing filters or sortings. So I finally gave up and changed the retrieving strategy to SQL query strings.

Comment: Using Martin Zikmund solution the query loaded in 5 seconds. Not great but a huge improvement.

Comment: I will test with SQL query strings as well and let you know the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems using the `GetAllWithChildren` is the problem. This method recursively loads the info of all the reviews, not just the one. You are then performing the ordering and selection **after** all the data returned from the DB.

The solution would be to first filter and only then return the `Review`:

```
var review = database.Table<Review>().Where(x => x.Product == prodId ).
              OrderByDescending( x => x.ReviewId ).FirstOrDefault();
database.GetChildren( review, true );
return element;
```

Comment: I tested both solutions and yours had the the best performance! Thank you so much

Comment: It improved from 17 to 5 seconds. :)

Comment: The `GetChildren` method with `true` for recursive really loads the whole tree of related objects and it seems it is not working too efficiently. You might be better off just manually running the select queries to get the objects you actually need and assign them to the review's properties.

Answer (score 2):

`database.GetAllWithChildren<Review>` returns a `List<Review>` of fully constructed reviews. This means that the more reviews a product has, the more reviews get discarded by `FirstOrDefault()` right after being constructed.

Try getting the max id first, then filter reviews on it:

```
// This assumes that ID is int. Change to another nullable type matching ReviewId
int? maxId = database.Reviews.Where(r => r.ProductId == prodId).Max((int?)r.ReviewId);
return database
    .GetAllWithChildren<Review>(x => x.ProductId == prodId && x.ReviewId == maxId, true)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: @MartinZikmund Right, I forgot to add the `Where` condition. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you I tested this and it worked. However Zikmund's solution had a slightly better performance. Thank you very much!